# hive left outer join with between condition

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I know we can't do un-equal joins in hive. I need to convert below query in to hive (hql). Any suggestions/workaround's would be appreciated.

Both table_A and table_B dose not have primary key.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_A f
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B dom1
 ON dom1.country = f.issuing_office_country
AND dom1.ulr_source = 'Loss'
AND dom1.valuation_class = f.dsp_level_join
AND dom1.year_type = 'UW'
AND f.undwrtr_yr_prd_fy_mnth BETWEEN dom1.start_year_month AND dom1.end_year_month

LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B dom2
 ON dom2.country = f.issuing_office_country
AND dom2.ulr_source = 'Short'
AND dom2.valuation_class = f.div_level_join 
AND dom2.year_type = 'UW'
AND f.undwrtr_yr_prd_fy_mnth BETWEEN dom2.start_year_month AND dom2.end_year_month
```

Comment: Can you move the inequality to a `where` clause?

Comment: I already tried that, where clause is applied once after the join is done. So I wont be getting same results. For Example: If there are no records matching on Join condition in Table_B am getting 0 records with where condition(I should be getting atleast left table rows).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix this (to a close approximation) by using a `where` clause.  It should read:

```
where (f.undwrtr_yr_prd_fy_mnth BETWEEN dom1.start_year_month AND dom1.end_year_month or
       dom1.valuation_class is null
      ) and
      (f.undwrtr_yr_prd_fy_mnth BETWEEN dom2.start_year_month AND dom2.end_year_month or
       dom2.valuation_class is null
      )
```

There are some subtle differences between having the condition in the `where` clause versus the `on` clause, but they probably will not affect your query.

Comment: No this wont get me same results. If where condition is not satisfied it will remove the whole row, but I should be getting atleast Left table values right(and right table values as nulls if Join condition is not satisfied)?

Comment: @sake . . . True, but it is checking for a `NULL` value in the second table of the `left join`.  So, a non-match will not cause the row to be filtered out.

Comment: lets say all Join conditions match except between condition, then this where condition will delete entire row right? ( I should have all left tables values with right tables as null). So this dose not work?

Comment: @sake . . . Nothing gets "deleted" merely "filtered".  If the `between` condition fails, then the first clause will fail and the second clause will fail so the row will not be in the result set.  Note:  I just changed the `or` to `and`.

Comment: please look at this test I did on sample data  http://imgur.com/gallery/8oRNZK5/new

Comment: @sake . . . Yes, that is a case where this method doesn't work.  It's a shame about the limitations of HQL.